# SysFolder Icons with TYPO3 Icon-API

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

Till TYPO3 CMS 6.2 i've been using the following code in extTables.php to provide sysfolder icons:

```
$TCA['pages']['columns']['module']['config']['items'][] = array('Templates', 'templates', '/fileadmin/icons/application_side_list.png');
\TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Sprite\SpriteManager::addTcaTypeIcon('pages', 'contains-templates', '/fileadmin/icons/application_side_list.png');
```

As since 7.6 the code is obsolete and icons are provided by the Icon-API. Am I right? So my question is, if it's still possible to provide sysfolder icons to the backend using BitmapIconProvider, SvgIconProvider or the FontawesomeIconProvider?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should work using the `IconRegistry` core class:

**ext_localconf.php:**

```
if (TYPO3_MODE === 'BE') {
    /** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconRegistry $iconRegistry */
    $iconRegistry = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconRegistry::class);
    $iconRegistry->registerIcon(
        'apps-pagetree-folder-contains-templates',
        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconProvider\BitmapIconProvider::class,
        ['source' => 'EXT:myext/Resources/Public/Icons/application_side_list.png']
    );
}
```

**ext_tables.php:**

```
if (TYPO3_MODE === 'BE') {
    $GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['columns']['module']['config']['items'][] = [
        0 => 'Templates',
        1 => 'templates',
        2 => 'apps-pagetree-folder-contains-templates'
    ];
}
```

Comment: That's great, thank's. One more question about the source. As I didn't have a extension and the imags are located in fileadmin folder, may I just use '/fileadmin/icons/application_side_list.png'? Because that's doesn't seem to work. Pagetree is showing "/typo3/sysext/core/Resources/Public/Icons/T3Icons/default/default-not-found.svg"

Comment: As far as I know it should be `FILE:fileadmin/icons/...`.

Comment: That's not working. It always shows the "not found" Icon. I've tried so much, thats really frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

The TYPO3 extension must be modified to fit the needs of TYPO3 7.5 and higher. Replace myextkey by the extension key of your extension.

**ext_localconf.php:**

```
if (TYPO3_MODE == 'BE') {
    $pageType = 'myext10'; // a maximum of 10 characters

    $icons = array(
        'apps-pagetree-folder-contains-' . $pageType => 'apps-pagetree-folder-contains-myextkey.svg'
    );
    /** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconRegistry $iconRegistry */
    $iconRegistry = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconRegistry::class);
    foreach ($icons as $identifier => $filename) {
        $iconRegistry->registerIcon(
            $identifier,
            $iconRegistry->detectIconProvider($filename),
            array('source' => 'EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Resources/Public/Icons/' . $filename)
        );
    }
}
```

**Configuration/TCA/Overrides/pages.php:**

```
<?php

if (!defined ('TYPO3_MODE')) {
    die ('Access denied.');
}

// add folder icon
$pageType = 'myext10'; // a maximum of 10 characters
$iconReference = 'apps-pagetree-folder-contains-' . $pageType;

$addToModuleSelection = TRUE;
foreach ($GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['columns']['module']['config']['items'] as $item) {
    if ($item['1'] == $pageType) {
        $addToModuleSelection = false;
        break;
    }
}

if ($addToModuleSelection) {
    $GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['ctrl']['typeicon_classes']['contains-' . $pageType] = $iconReference;

    $GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['columns']['module']['config']['items'][] = array(
        0 => 'LLL:EXT:myextkey/locallang.xml:pageModule.plugin',
        1 => $pageType,
        2 => $iconReference
    );
}

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::registerPageTSConfigFile(
    $pageType,
    'Configuration/TSconfig/Page/folder_tables.txt',
    'EXT:myextkey :: Restrict pages to myextkey records'
);
```

**locallang.xml:**

```
<label index="pageModule.plugin">My Extension: Table names of my extension</label>
```

**Resources/Public/Icons/apps-pagetree-folder-contains-myextkey.svg:**
vector graphic image file for your extension tables

see https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.Icons for working example SVG icons.

**Configuration/TSconfig/Page/folder_tables.txt:**
Insert the table names of your extension.

```
mod.web_list.allowedNewTables = tx_myextkey_tablename1, tx_myextkey_tablename2, tx_myextkey_tablename3
```